# Just checking: abstain vote from Symfony AbstractVoter isGranted

Tags: php, security, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony2 application in which we want to introduce [Security Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html). The DX initiative (jay!) brought us [the simpler version](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-simpler-security-voters) of this mechanism so I'd like to use that. The only thing that's bothering me a bit about the use of `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\AbstractVoter` is the fact that I can no longer abstain a vote when just implementing the abstract `isGranted` method. I'd like to change that for our application but would really appreciate your opinion on the matter from a security point of view.

To be clear, in our application we will be using the `unanimous` access decision manager strategy - in short: you need at least one `ACCESS_GRANTED` and no `ACCESS_DENIED` - because we might later want to introduce voters for banning IP addresses or other shenanigans.

As shown in the relevant piece of code below, as soon as an implementation of the `AbstractVoter` supports an attribute, the vote will default to `Denied`.

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{
    if (!$object || !$this->supportsClass(get_class($object))) {
        return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    // abstain vote by default in case none of the attributes are supported
    $vote = self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if (!$this->supportsAttribute($attribute)) {
            continue;
        }

        // as soon as at least one attribute is supported, default is to deny access
        $vote = self::ACCESS_DENIED;

        if ($this->isGranted($attribute, $object, $token->getUser())) {
            // grant access as soon as at least one voter returns a positive response
            return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }
    }

    return $vote;
}
```

What I'd like to do is override that with the code below

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{
    if (!$object || !$this->supportsClass(get_class($object))) {
        return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    $vote = self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if (!$this->supportsAttribute($attribute)) {
            continue;
        }

        // This is where we differ from SymfonyAbstractVoter. Only if there is an outspoken yes or no, a vote is cast
        // When returning null, it will still abstain
        $grant = $this->isGranted($attribute, $object, $token->getUser());
        if ($grant === true) {
            return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }
        if($grant === false) {
            return self::ACCESS_DENIED;
        }

    }

    return $vote;
}
```

What do you think? Is it safe to return `ACCESS_ABSTAIN` when null is returned form `isGranted` and only cast a `ACCESS_GRANTED` or `ACCESS_DENIED` if a voter returns true or false?

---

Why would I even want to do this? To still make use of the `AbstractVoter` (because, yes I'm a lazy developer) but separate my concerns.

Let's say I make one voter for a post, `PostVoter`, that will allow me to edit my own posts. It will then cast a `ACCESS_GRANTED`. But as long as I don't own the post, this voter really doesn't care: it should just cast an `ACCESS_ABSTAIN`. 
Later on it might run into an `AdminVoter` that will still cast an `ACCESS_GRANTED`. 
When using the `unanimous` access decision manager strategy, however, if this `PostVoter` already casted an `ACCESS_DENIED` it will never get to any other voters.

I can't cast that `ACCESS_ABSTAIN` in the `AbstractVoter` now without overriding the `vote` method and the whole point of simpler voters in my mind was, well, to make it simpler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AbstractVoter` class is a simple bootstrap implementation for majority of use cases and it emulates how [internal](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/AuthenticatedVoter.php#L71) [voters](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/ExpressionVoter.php#L84) [behave](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/RoleVoter.php#L64), so as soon as you feel your solution differs from the base case, you should feel free to override with your own methods.